# Glimpse diagnostics platform which is full compatible to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

I used [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) on the old ASP.NET MVC5 stack and liked it very much cause it gives a pretty and detailed representation of nearly all important data for debugging purpose. Sadly, its not compatible with ASP.NET Core (yet). I tried to install the [demo](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2015/11/19/installing-glimpse-v2-beta1/), which assurance to work with ASP.NET Core.

But thats not entirely true cause it works on ASP.NET Core, but depends on the old 4.x framework. So it destroys the cross-platform compability, which is not suiteable for me. The app is designed to run on a Linux based server using docker.

Although, I would like to benefit from those nice features in my Core app, too. Is there any similar alternative to Glimpse that is full compatible to ASP.NET Core? I'm currently using ASP.NET Core 1.1, but could also downgrade to 1.0 if necessary. The most important things for me are request duration and database (SQL) querys, may Redis included if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore.

It can profile MVC and Entity Framework and it has an UI representation via a Tag helper

Answer (score -1):

You can try https://stackify.com/prefix/ - although it is a self hosted web app so it is not as "deployable" / works best on local development. It uses profiling so it is less intrusive on the code stack.

Core: http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/articles/209962473-Using-Prefix-with-ASP-NET-Core-Kestrel

Comment: Seems good from the demo. I tried it, but sadly, it doesn't work on ASP.NET Core, even it's compatible with it. I made a new question for this since its another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763348/stackify-prefix-doesnt-collect-any-data-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Doesn't work for me with ASP.NET Core - nothing appears in the profiling web app