# Stackify Prefix doesn't collect any data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware, stackify

I tried Prefix from Stackify as an alternative to [Glimpse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695729/glimpse-diagnostics-platform-which-is-full-compatible-to-asp-net-core/41753994#41753994), which doesn't support native ASP.NET Core.

According to [this article](http://pioneercode.com/post/profiling-asp-net-core-with-stackify-prefix) and the docs, I installed the server application using chocolately. Then installed the NuGet-Package `StackifyMiddleware` and activated it in the `Configure` method - bevor MVC is added, like mentioned in the official docs. Finally, I activated .NET profiling using the tray icon and re-opened Visual Studio.

The browser opened the data overview page of Prefix (http://localhost:2012), but no information is collected. I have no hint what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running an ASP.NET Core app via Visual Studio? With IIS Express or directly?

Here is our docs about this: http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/articles/209962473-Using-Prefix-with-ASP-NET-Core-Kestrel

Comment: @MattWatson Thanks for the answear, cool that you're directly supporting our product here! :) I used Krestel (so without IIS) and already found this article in our kb. Now I tried this on a brand new ASP.NET core app (Visual Studio 2015 default template) and it works. Is Prefix not compatible with .NET Core 1.1? That's the only difference I can see. The new test-app is running 1.0.1 cause Visual Studio doesn't have updated their templates yet. My real project-app use 1.1.0.

Comment: @MattWatson - did everything your docs recommend - still no luck. IIS express hosted version works fine, self-hosted doesn't seem to hit prefix at all. Any pointers? (Neither Core 1.0, nor Core 1.1, nor Core 2.0 work)

Comment: @MattWatson Followed your docs and did all the steps in it. Did not work for me! My project is also built with 1.1.0.

Comment: I'm trying StackifyMiddleware with IIS as reverse proxy and I don't get much data. For example, it doesn't even show the Request (header and etc) and Response that were made. It only says that I request was made. Is that normal?

Comment: Same here, using IIS. ASP Core 2. Visual studio community 2017.

Comment: I have the same issue if "IIS Express" is used, if I use "IIS" - it works!

Comment: @MattWatson Same issue VS 2017 (15.9.5) with ASP.NET Core 2.1 or 2.2 + IIS Express

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem creating a file named Stackify.json in the deployment folder of your application with

{
"AppName": "MyApp"
}